# Fixed IP address for Epson SX420W

Tags: windows-7, printer, static-ip

I bought this cheap printer at the supermarket (shame on me! 80€ - 20€ coupon! Double shame :-P) and while I found it easy to configure Wi-Fi with WPS, I see it obviously never gets the same IP from my ISP-provided home router.

This makes me unable to print until I manually change the IP settings in the printer's port.
Any ideas on how to configure static IP?

Thanks

Comment: can you set your home router to assign it the same IP? Most home routers can assign the same address based on MAC address. Or, if you can manually set it in the printer, limit the DHCP range in the router and set the static in the printer to be an address outside the DHCP range.

Comment: @MaQleod: impossible. The router is ISP-owned and controlled. I have no way to set it up :(

Comment: So add a second router. Double-NAT is not ideal, but it will hand DHCP to your router, and you can control the DHCP config of your internal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Network manual on this page
http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX420W/Drivers-Support;jsessionid=D63283D2C64B7168B87B3BC986BC51C6.acc6-new

Once you unpack the zip file look in the EN folder it created and click the Index.htm, when your browset opens the manual go to "Set Up Using Control Panel and OS Functions, then click "Setup Printer LAN using the Control Panel" then refer to #6

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to Epson's [Network Guide](http://support.epson-europe.com/onlineguides/en/fy10_nwg/html/index.htm) for that printer, you can set the network up manually using the "[EpsonNet Setup](http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX420W/Drivers-Support?target=driver&languageId=1&driverId=326529&defaultOSId=22&DRV_CATEGORY_CODE=NETUTILS)" software.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can still enter the printer's host name instead of IP address.

The printer gets detected by Windows network screen so I can grab its name.

Answer (score -1):

I also have an Epson Stylus SX420W (bought in Spain).

I am unable to set a static ip address from the printer control panel. Doing the sequence:
1) Enter **Setup** Mode
2) Select **Network Settings**,
the only options are:

a) **Wireless LAN Setup**

b) **Check Network Connection**

c) **Print Network Status**

None of these allow me to setup a static ip address.

Previously, I set up the Wifi router to assign a static ip address to the MAC address of the printer. That worked fine. (However, I now have a new router which I am not allowed to administer.)

Comment: Your supposed to answer to a question in here. If you want to ask a new question, ask a question using the button on right top of the page.

Comment: Yes, my text was intended to suggest that Moab's answer was not always correct. (Couldn't find a comment button on his/her post)

Comment: But did you know you answered to a post from November 2011? Probably the firmware is changed. You can search for a new manual.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the date. If you know where to get newer firmware, that would be useful (I have not succeeded myself). Don't think I need a new manual. Thanks for your help, although I think you are getting a little off-topic.